# How to post dropdownlist viewbag values to sql server using mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting dynamic values in dropdownlist through viewbag,dropdownlist values is displaying properly but my problem is posting,I am getting problem to insert dropdownlist values in sql server,please help me to solve this problem.

This is my model page,

```
public class RegisterModel
{
  public Prefix Prefix { get; set; }
}

public class Prefix
{
  public int? ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }      
}
```

This is my controller page,

```
void BindPrefix()
{
  List<Prefix> lstPrefix = new List<Prefix>()
  {
    new Prefix { ID = null, Name = "Select" },
    new Prefix { ID = 1, Name = "Mr" },
    new Prefix { ID = 2, Name = "Ms" },
    new Prefix { ID = 1, Name = "Mrs" },
    new Prefix { ID = 2, Name = "Dr" }
  };
  ViewBag.Prefix = lstPrefix;
}

public ActionResult Register()
{
  BindPrefix();     
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]       
public ActionResult Register(FormCollection FC)
{
  string Prefix =FC[ViewBag.Prefix]; // here prefix get null value.
  return view();
}
```

This is my view page,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Prefix.ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Prefix, "ID", "Name", ViewBag.pef))
```

Comment: ViewBag information persist per request, that is the reason why you have ViewBag.Prefix equal to null in the post action.

Comment: You view is based on model `RegisterModel` so post back the model `public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)` which will be correctly bound

Comment: i used ActionResult but i is also showing null because Prefix is Boolean datatype

Comment: `Prefix` is **not** typeof `boolean`. Its a complex type containing properties `int? ID` and `string Name` and you should change the `ViewBag` property to another name e.g. `ViewBag.PrefixList = lstPrefix;` and remove the 4th parameter the SelectList constructor

Comment: And remove the first item form `lstPrefix`, and instead use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Prefix.ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.PrefixList, "ID", "Name"), "Select")`. And why are your ID values not unique (you have two '1' and two '2') - how would you know what was selected? And why do you need a complex property anyway - whats wrong with just selecting a string ("Mr", Ms" etc)

Comment: thank you Stephen Muecke sir,exactly your are saying write,i got output..as based on ID but I need Name as output..please help me

Comment: @Gowthamg, Then why are your using `class Prefix`? Whats the point of having an `ID` and `Name` property if you don't want or use the `ID` property?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get Selected Value,You have to get from the Drop down name which generate:

```
string Prefix =FC["Prefix"];
```

Currently this :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Prefix.ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Prefix, "ID", "Name", ViewBag.pef))
```

will generate this html:

```
<select id="Prefix_ID" name="Prefix.ID">
.........
.........
</select>
```

and using Element name in form Collection will give you the value.

```
string Prefix =FC["Prefix.ID"].ToString();
```

Comment: It will generate `<select id="Prefix_ID" name="Prefix.ID">` so its `string Prefix =FC["Prefix.ID"];`

Comment: Thanks for replying sir,how to generate dropdownlist in html

Comment: when i keep my dropdownlist inside the html,view output not displaying values in dropdownlist,how to i present dropdownlist values in html <select> tag.

Comment: exactly you are saying correct,i got output thanks for every one...i got output based on id but i need output based on name,please help me.

Comment: What you mean by that, you want name to be posted??

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments that you only want to display and post back a 'title', the use of class `Prefix` seems unnecessary

View model

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a title")]
  public string Title { get; set }
  // other properties
  public SelectList TitleList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
  RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
  ConfigureViewModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  // save and redirect
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(RegisterViewModel model)
{
  List<string> titles = new List<string>) { "Mr.", "Ms", "Mrs", "Dr." };
  model.TitleList = new SelectList(titles);
}
```

View

```
@model RegisterViewModel
...
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, Model.TitleList, "-Please select-")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
  ....
}
```

Comment: I guess not. Best of luck getting any help in the future.